# Quicktime player: merging multiple videos results in much greater file size than original clips

Tags: quicktime, video-editing

I used Quicktime player to merge multiple videos.

#### Info:

- The file size of all the original clips that I merged is 3.06GB
- Used HEVC codec
- Source is also HEVC

#### Resolution and size of merged videos

- resolution of original videos: 1080p and 720p
- 1080p filesize: 11GB
- 720p filesize: 9.09GB
- 480p filesize: 3.2GB

Don't want to use 480p as there is a noticeable difference in quality (of course, but I tested to make sure).

#### Question:

Why is the file size of the merged videos greater than the original clips and is there anyway around this?

#### More info:

A huge increase of file size only happens when I convert to 1080p whether the source is 720p or 1080p.

When converting to 720p whether the source is 1080p or 720p there is only a slight increase in file size.

Comment: Were the source videos also encoded with HEVC? It's going to be tricky to rationalise the difference unless the source and destination video and audio codecs are the same. Also there may be container overhead. Unfortunately not my area of expertise. It may be worth supplying some data from an app such as MediaInfo (free in the App store) for both your source and merged videos.Then someone else may have more insight.

Comment: note: a huge increase of file size only happens when I convert to 1080p whether the source is 720p or 1080p. When converting to 720p whether the source is 1080p or 720p there is only a slight increase in file size. I used the app you mentioned and the codecs are the same for audio and video.